# Django view getting called twice (double GET request)

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm creating a classifieds website in Django. A single view function handles global listings, city-wise listings, barter-only global listings and barter-only city-wise listings. This view is called `ads`.

The url patterns are written in the following order (note that each has a unique name although it's tied to the same `ads` view):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^buy_and_sell/$', ads,name='classified_listing'),
    url(r'^buy_and_sell/barter/$', ads,name='barter_classified_listing'),
    url(r'^buy_and_sell/barter/(?P<city>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ads,name='city_barter_classified_listing'),
    url(r'^buy_and_sell/(?P<city>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ads,name='city_classified_listing'),
)
```

The problem is that when I hit the url named `classified_listing` in the list above, the function `ads` gets called **twice**. I.e. here's what I see in my terminal:

```
[14/Jul/2017 14:31:08] "GET /buy_and_sell/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53758 
[14/Jul/2017 14:31:08] "GET /buy_and_sell/None/ HTTP/1.1" 200 32882
```

This means double the processing. I thought `urls.py` returns the first url pattern matched. What am I doing wrong and what's the best way to fix this? All other calls work as expected btw (i.e. only once).

*Note: Ask for more information in case I've missed something.*

---

Great explanation to understand these type of occurences: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/CRMMYWix_60/KEIkguUcqxYJ

Comment: I'm not sure why it's happening twice, but you should reorder them to have the most specific one first (barter/city)

Comment: @Brobin: Aren't `^buy_and_sell/$` and `^buy_and_sell/barter/$` more specific than the other two? These are constant strings, whereas a regex implies a range of values.

Comment: Normally a double call is caused by an asset reference within the template - eg image or stylesheet - pointing to the wrong thing. Show your template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Well the template is moderately big - but I'll try to add the simplest working example for you. Meanwhile, can you tell me 1) am I essentially looking for erroneous `href` and/or `src` tags? 2) howcome when being called a second time, the url in `GET` is `/buy_and_sell/None/` and not just `buy_and_sell/`?

Comment: Because you've got a url reference which is being resolved to just "None". Since that doesn't start with a slash, the browser is treating it as a relative link and appending it to the current URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with how url patterns are ordered in `urls.py`.

Like pointed out in the comments under the question, this has to do with problematic asset references in the HTML template.

What does that mean?

For instance, try `curl -i http://localhost:8000/example/ >> output.txt` in your terminal. Then open up `output.txt` in your editor of choice. Now search for `href` or `src` attributes where values are `None` (or otherwise malformed). That's one reason a double call is being created. That was the reason for me. I removed these, and the double call disappeared.

There's this old - but relevant - writeup about how to comprehensively diagnose this problem on your machine here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/CRMMYWix_60/KEIkguUcqxYJ

Happy testing.

Comment: Amazing - what an inference excellent  HassanBaig and as always @DanielRosman , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment on other answers, just to add for future wanderers that for me the "problem" was in a correctly formed but yet for the browser instructing `<iframe src="#"..>` tag. On django server the view was rendering twice, once with original request and then again by the hidden iframe element that I used for some of the modal popups later in the page usage.

After emptying the `src` attribute like `<iframe src=""..>` a second request is no longer initiated and my modals work fine.

The solution actually is from the link posted already in answers before [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/CRMMYWix_60/KEIkguUcqxYJ][1]
where it is explained:

> Note that it's a URI. That means something that is retrieved. Since
>   you've used the value "#fff", that will be interpreted by the browser as
>   a reference to the current page (#fff being an anchor, and not passed to
>   the server). Ergo, a second request is made.

that the iframe src # (anchor) is instructing the browser to load again the same URL, for the iframe element in my case.
I indeed had several `style` elements with `#fff` colors inside and whatnot, but this wasn't it, as browsers are smart enough to recognize this is not an anchor.

With available tools (browser only) I found to be easy to debug and find these initiation href/src attributes over the Network tab of your browser developer tools - in Chrome is just by clicking the Initiator link of the corresponding row - giving you the exact line from the page source that initiated the request to the same URL.

Comment: I spent 4 hours solving this problem and I thought it was just an explosion of the tower in my view! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem and just wanted to share my experience with it. I had double requests all over my application but everything seemed to work as expected apart form it.

What Daniel Rossman pointet out in the comments was actually also true for my problem. I had a `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">` in my base template which caused the double request, because of the `#`, which is a reference to the page itself. Once i removed it, i had no double requests anymore.

Hope this answer can save someone some debugging time.

Comment: I had a `href=""` and I added the hash and it removed my double get calls. So I ended up with `href="#"` to fix my problem...lovely consistency!

Answer (score 1):

I got double request in view function, in my scenario, this went wrong:

```html
<img id="profile-img" src="#" alt="" class="profile-cover">
```

by setting `src=""` dismiss double request. it was a silly thing, I just thought it apply to `a` then must apply to `img`, but `img` actually send another request.

Comment: same problem if src="/"