# Django why my post.count_views increments by 2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Good evening, everyone, I'm a beginner at Django I have blog page details that has count views and category for the blog post and blog post tags and other staff

my post model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    tagss = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True, related_name='post')
    Categorys = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, related_name='post')
    views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my view is:

```
def post_page(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug = slug)
    post.views_count = post.views_count + 1
    post.save()
    print("views:", post.views_count ) 
    
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    tags = Tags.objects.all()
    
    # change 2 to how many random items you want
    random_items = list(Post.objects.all().order_by('?')[:2]) 
    
    related_posts = list(
        Post.objects.filter(
            Q(tagss__name__in=[tag.name for tag in post.tagss.all()]) | 
            Q(Categorys__name__in=[Category.name for Category in post.Categorys.all()])
        ).distinct()
    )
   
    recent_posts  = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:4]
    
    
    context = {'post': post, 'cats': cats, 'tags': tags, 'recent_posts': recent_posts,
               'random_blog': random_items, 'related_posts': related_posts}
    
    return render(request, 'blog/Blog_details.html', context)
```

and that's my url.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog', views.blogs, name='blog'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>', views.post_page, name= 'blog_page')
```

and that's my Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}SAS | Cosmetics Blog details {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<main id="content" class="wrapper layout-page">
    <section class="z-index-2 position-relative pb-2 mb-12">
        <div class="bg-body-secondary mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="py-4 lh-30px" aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center py-1 mb-0">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a title="Home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Blog Update</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="pt-10 pb-16 pb-lg-18">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="position-sticky top-0">
                        <aside class="primary-sidebar mt-12 pt-2 mt-lg-0 pt-lg-0 pe-xl-9 me-xl-2">
                            <div class="widget widget-search">
                                <h4 class="widget-title fs-5 mb-6">Search</h4>
                                <form action="#">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <button type="submit"
                                            class="input-group-text bg-transparent px-4 border-0 position-absolute z-index-4 text-body-emphasis fs-5 start-0 top-0 bottom-0 m-auto"><svg
                                                class="icon icon-magnifying-glass-light">
                                                <use xlink:href="#icon-magnifying-glass-light"></use>
                                            </svg></button>
                                        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control ps-11"
                                            placeholder="Search">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget widget-category">
                                <h4 class="widget-title fs-5 mb-6">Category</h4>
                                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-cate" id="widget_category">
                                    {% for category in cats %}
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" title="{{category.name}}"
                                            class="text-reset position-relative d-block text-decoration-none text-body-emphasis-hover d-flex align-items-center"><span
                                                class="text-hover-underline">{{category.name}}</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget widget-post">
                                <h4 class="widget-title fs-5 mb-6">Recent posts</h4>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 row gy-7 gx-0">
                                    {% for recent in recent_posts %}
                                    <li class="col-12">
                                        <div class="card border-0 flex-row">
                                            <figure class="flex-shrink-0 mb-0 me-7">
                                                <a href="{% url "blog_page" recent.slug %}" class="d-block"
                                                    title="{{recent.title}}">
                                                    <img data-src="{{recent.image.url}}"
                                                        class="lazy-image"
                                                        alt="{{recent.title}}" width="60"
                                                        height="80" src="#">
                                                </a>
                                            </figure>
                                            <div class="card-body p-0">
                                                <h5
                                                    class="card-text fw-semibold ls-1 text-uppercase fs-13px mb-3 text-body text-primary-hover">
                                                    <a class="text-decoration-none text-reset" href="{{recent.Categorys.first.slug}}"
                                                        title="Skin care">{{recent.Categorys.first.name}}</a></h5>
                                                <h4
                                                    class="card-title mb-0 text-body-emphasis fs-15px lh-base text-primary-hover">
                                                    <a class="text-decoration-none text-reset"
                                                        href="{% url "blog_page" recent.slug %}"
                                                        title="{{recent.title}}">{{recent.title}}</a></h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget widget-banner">
                                <div class="card border-0">
                                    <img class="card-img img-fluid lazy-image"
                                        data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/blog/widget-banner-img.jpg" %}"
                                        alt="Be your kind of beauty" width="340" height="343" src="#">
                                    <div
                                        class="card-img-overlay pt-8 pb-7 px-xl-14 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <h2 class="fw-semibold text-uppercase fs-30px lh-12 text-white text-center">
                                            Be your kind of beauty</h2>
                                        <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-white shadow-none">
                                            Explore More
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget widget-tags">
                                <h4 class="widget-title fs-5 mb-6">Tags</h4>
                                <ul class="w-100 mt-n4 list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap mb-0">
                                    {% for tag in tags  %}
                                    <li class="me-6 mt-4">
                                        <a href="#" title="{{tag.name}}"
                                            class="text-reset d-block text-decoration-none text-body-emphasis-hover text-hover-underline">{{tag.name}}</a>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget widget-instagram">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline justify-content-between">
                                    <h4 class="widget-title fs-5 mb-6">Follow us</h4><a href="#"
                                        class="text-primary text-hover-underline">@GRACE</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row g-10px">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-01.jpg" %} " title="instagram-01"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-01-106x106.jpg" %} "
                                                alt="instagram-01" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-02.jpg" %}" title="instagram-02"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-02-106x106.jpg" %}"
                                                alt="instagram-02" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-03.jpg" %}" title="instagram-03"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-03-106x106.jpg" %}"
                                                alt="instagram-03" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-04.jpg" %}" title="instagram-04"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-04-106x106.jpg" %}"
                                                alt="instagram-04" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-05.jpg" %}" title="instagram-05"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-05-106x106.jpg" %}"
                                                alt="instagram-05" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a class="card-img-overlay-hover hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                            href="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-06.jpg" %}" title="instagram-06"
                                            data-gallery="widget_instagram">
                                            <img class="lazy-image img-fluid w-100" width="106" height="106"
                                                data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/instagram/instagram-06-106x106.jpg" %}"
                                                alt="instagram-06" src="#">
                                            <span class="card-img-overlay bg-dark bg-opacity-30"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class=" text-center mb-13">
                        {% if post.Categorys.all %}
                        <a href="#"
                            class="btn btn-light btn-hover-bg-dark btn-hover-border-dark btn-hover-text-light shadow-none py-0 px-6 mb-6">
                            {{ post.Categorys.first.name }}
                        </a>
                        {% endif %}
                        <h2 class=" px-6 text-body-emphasis border-0 fw-500 mb-4 fs-3 ">
                            {{post.title}}
                        </h2>
                        <ul
                            class="list-inline fs-15px fw-semibold letter-spacing-01 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <li><img data-src="{% static "blog/assets/images/blog/post-detail-header-img.png" %}" alt="Grace"
                                    class="lazy-image img-fluid" src="#"></li>
                            <li class="border-end px-6 text-body-emphasis border-0 text-body">
                                By
                                <a href="#">Admin</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item px-6">{{post.post_date|date:"M d, Y"}}</li>
                            <li class="ms-5 list-style-disc">{{post.views_count}} view{{post.views_count|pluralize}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <img data-src="{{post.image.url}}" width="770" height="470" alt=""
                            class="lazy-image mb-12 img-fluid" src="#">
                            {{post.content|safe}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-gutters pt-11 justify-content-sm-between">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                            <ul class="list-inline fw-semibold">
                                {% for tag in post.tagss.all %}
                                <li class="list-inline-item me-3">
                                    <a href=""
                                        class="text-body text-body-emphasis-hover text-decoration-none">#{{tag.name}}</a>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-sm-end">
                            <label class="text-secondary fw-semibold me-7 mb-0">Share:</label>
                            <ul class="list-inline mb-0 lh-1">
                                <li class="list-inline-item me-7">
                                    <a href="" class="fs-18px lh-14 fw-normal">
                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item me-7">
                                    <a href="" class="fs-18px lh-14 fw-normal">
                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item me-7">
                                    <a href="" class="fs-18px lh-14 fw-normal">
                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item me-7">
                                    <a href="" class="fs-18px lh-14 fw-normal">
                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 mt-5 mb-7">
                            <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                        </div>
                        {% if random_blog %}
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="ml-8">
                                <p class="fs-13px ls-1 text-uppercase mb-5 fw-semibold px-8">
                                    {{ random_blog.0.Categorys.first.name }}
                                </p>
                                <a href="{{ random_blog.0.slug }}" class="fs-15px fw-semibold position-relative px-8">
                                    <i class="far fa-chevron-left mt-2 position-absolute start-0 top-0"></i>
                                    {{ random_blog.0.title }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-sm-end">
                            <div class="mr-8 text-right">
                                <p class="fs-13px text-start text-sm-end ls-1 text-uppercase mb-5 fw-semibold px-8">
                                    {{random_blog.1.Categorys.first.name}}
                                </p>
                                <a href="{{ random_blog.1.slug }}"
                                    class="fs-15px text-start text-sm-end fw-semibold position-relative px-8">
                                    <i class="far fa-chevron-right mt-2 position-absolute end-0 top-0"></i>
                                    {{ random_blog.1.title }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>

                    {% if related_posts %}

                    <div class="pt-14 pb-13 pb-lg-15 pt-lg-18 mx-n5" id="post_related">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-6 fs-3">Related Posts</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container container-xxl mt-10 pt-3">
                            <div class="slick-slider"
                                data-slick-options="{&#34;arrows&#34;:false,&#34;dots&#34;:true,&#34;responsive&#34;:[{&#34;breakpoint&#34;:1200,&#34;settings&#34;:{&#34;slidesToShow&#34;:3}},{&#34;breakpoint&#34;:992,&#34;settings&#34;:{&#34;dots&#34;:true,&#34;slidesToShow&#34;:2}},{&#34;breakpoint&#34;:768,&#34;settings&#34;:{&#34;dots&#34;:true,&#34;slidesToShow&#34;:1}}],&#34;slidesToShow&#34;:3}">
                                {% for post in related_posts %}
                                <div>
                                    <article class="card card-post-grid-3 bg-transparent border-0"
                                        data-animate="fadeInUp">
                                        <figure class="card-img-top mb-8 position-relative"><a href="{{post.slug}}"
                                                class="hover-shine hover-zoom-in d-block"
                                                title="{{post.title}}">
                                                <img data-src="{{post.image.url}}"
                                                    class="img-fluid lazy-image w-100"
                                                    alt="Our Favorite Multitasking Products" width="237"
                                                    height="288" src="#">
                                            </a></figure>
                                        <div class="card-body p-0">
                                            <ul
                                                class="post-meta list-inline lh-1 d-flex flex-wrap fs-13px text-uppercase ls-1 fw-semibold m-0">
                                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a
                                                        class="text-reset text-decoration-none text-primary-hover"
                                                        href="#" title="{{post.Categorys.first.name}}">{{post.Categorys.first.name}}</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <h4 class="card-title fs-6 lh-base mt-5 pt-2 mb-0">
                                                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{post.slug}}"
                                                    title="{{post.title}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

{% endblock content %}
```

my problem is when I refresh the post page the views increase by 2 I need when the user refresh the page increase by 1
Thanks everyone

Comment: That's your entire model? Not some additional code (overriding `.save()` for example).

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem yeah that's my whole model the rest models about tags and category and don't have any save method

Comment: You don't have any context processor or something similar?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I don't know what you mean, but that's all I wrote into my code
and the page of course has for loop at tags and categories

Comment: Are you using Django to render your templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about calling the post_view() view function twice. There are some common scenarios that causes that problem:

1. Your post_view() function might be triggered when modern browsers sends ´OPTIONS´ and ´GET´ requests together. You can change your code as this for only handling ´GET´ requests:

```
def post_page(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)  # This is a cleaner way to get the object or 404
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Increment view count only if the request is a GET request
        Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(views_count=F('views_count') + 1)
        post.refresh_from_db()  # Refresh the instance after the update
    
        ... rest of your code ...

    return render(request, 'blog/Blog_details.html', context)
```

2. Please inspect this, it might be about your template files: [Misusing img tags causes double calling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544228/6266750) It might be about favicon, also: [Misusing favicon link tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174971/6266750)

Comment: Thanks @M Burak It solved by removing the href="#" and replaced it with href="" for links and src="#" with src="" for images, but that was so strange !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to increase views count like this by +1

```
def post_page(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug = slug)
    post.views_count += 1
    post.save()
    print("views:", post.views_count )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to see urls.py and template file? I guess you are calling the post_page function twice mistakenly.